# Clean way to properly check if phone number is not false in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
id  phone_number  
0   5555555555
1   9082345324
2   2345098345
```

I would like to run a one liner or a clean way of saying:

- If the number has all the same digits, remove it

Output should look like this:

```
id  phone_number  
1   9082345324
2   2345098345
```

My approach would be to use `iterrows()`, and for each phone number put each digit into a list, and cross compare the list using `lst[1:] == lst[:-1]` to see if all the digits are the same.  If they are, remove that row from DF.. I just want a more clean solution

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? SO isn't really meant to be a code-writing service, we're here to help you figure out the problems with your own code.

Comment: Edited my logic above.

Comment: You could run some filter that removes duplicate digits, if you have one remaining number , it contained only duplicates. I do hope 55555555... etc is guaranteed to be invalid

Comment: Can you write it in the form of a reproducible block of code, and explain why the output doesn't match what you expected?

Comment: Are the phone numbers always 10 digits long?

Comment: Phone numbers are always 10 digits.  I'm not looking for code help, I have it working. I just want a cleaner solution or ideas for a cleaner solution.

Comment: If you have it working why don't you show us the code?

Comment: *I just want a cleaner solution or ideas for a cleaner solution* how could we recommend something better without knowing what the baseline is?

Comment: There are other conditions that make a valid (10 digit North American) phone number. For instance 1234567890 meets your criteria, but is not valid. (Interestingly, 5555555555 is actually valid).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `set` and check the length

```
df[df.phone_number.apply(set).str.len().gt(1)]

  id phone_number
1  1   9082345324
2  2   2345098345
```

Equivalent using comprehension

```
df[[len({*x}) > 1 for x in df.phone_number]]
```

---

If those are actual integers

```
df[df.phone_number.astype(str).apply(set).str.len().gt(1)]
# df[[len({*str(x)}) > 1 for x in df.phone_number]]
```

---

Further bullet proofing assuming there might be non-digits in there

```
df[df.phone_number.astype(str).replace('\D', '').apply(set).str.len().gt(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, convert phone numbers to strings, if not already. Then, you need to check the number of occurrences of the first `character` in the phone number. If that matches the length of the phone number, that record should be removed.

```
df.phone_number = df.phone_number.apply(str)
df = df.loc[~df['phone_number'].apply(lambda x: x.count(x[0]) == len(x))]
```

Output:

```
id  phone_number
1   1   9082345324
2   2   2345098345
```